# In SSIS can the default font attributes be set for annotations?

Tags: ssis

In SSIS, can the default font attributes for annotations be set?

Every time I create a new annotation, I have to change the font because the default size is too small. But I cannot find anywhere to set the default (if possible).

I have searched the documentation and Google and found no answer for this. I thought perhaps maybe it could be hacked into some xml file or such a thing, but I don't know a lot about the ones in SSIS.